# InvalidArgumentError when running tf.global_variables_initializer()

Tags: tensorflow

Basically, I have a function that expects a tensor **x** and two placeholders **z** and **c**.

```
def error_robust(x,z,c):
  zz = tf.reshape(z, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
  var = tf.reduce_mean(x-zz)
  out = tf.cond( tf.abs(var) <= c, lambda: (c*c/6.0)*(1 - tf.pow(1-tf.pow(var/c,2),3)), lambda: tf.Variable(c*c/6.0) )
  return out
```

I define the placeholders and tensors that I am gonna use:

```
# TENSORFLOW PLACEHOLDERS
sess  = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True))
flat_mnist_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28*28])
dropout_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
param_robust = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=())
```

Calling the defined function does not generate any errors:

```
error_r = error_robust(layer1_b.reconstruction, flat_mnist_data, param_robust)
```

This generates an error:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
>        [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]]

I don't really understand why it happens. Any ideas on how to solve this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. I was first expecting **c** to be a simple scalar. So I was using tf.Variable as the second argument of the tf.cond. 
Updating the error_robust function solves it:

```
def error_robust(x,z,c):
  zz = tf.reshape(z, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
  var = tf.reduce_mean(x-zz)
  out = tf.cond( tf.abs(var) <= c, lambda: (c*c/6.0)*(1 - tf.pow(1-tf.pow(var/c,2),3)), lambda: c*c/6.0 )
  return out
```